# Proxy/VPN client-server setup where the server initates connection?

Tags: linux, proxy, linux-networking

The goal is to forward all traffic from computer **A** thorugh computer **B**.

The problem is that **B**'s firewall blocks all incoming connection, so typical proxy servers won't work here. At the same time, there is no firewall on **A**. So the idea is that **B** should connect to **A** and then **A** would forward all its traffic through **B**.

How to implement this?

Comment: What is the problem configuring firewall on B's side to allow connections? (I guess, in a *business environment* which is the setting this site is all about, there should be not much of a problem requiring the change of the firewall.) // That said, you can quite easily implement that with WireGuard, OpenVPN, Tinc and so on. Try to read their manuals. For example, in WireGuard protocol there is no "server" and "cient"; once the connection initiated by either side, both sides are equal (subject to IP filters set by AllowedIPs settings).

Comment: Also, you'll be *required* to alter firewall on the B, at very least to add the NAT rule into it. So it is inevitable.